# Проверка на наличие объектов. Тестирование

Tags: java, junit

Хочу протестировать метод, а он ничего не возвращает по какой-то неизвестной причине. Проходился дебаггером, в freehouse нет объектов, а они должны быть, потому в бд есть квартиры. Есть ли какой-нибудь тест, чтобы проверить в целом на наличие каких-либо объектов, а не конкретных, хотел бы им воспользоваться. Но этот до сих пор неизвестно почему возвращает пустоту. В связи с тем, что в приложении для запросов необходима авторизация, также добавил ещё один метод `Before`. Надеюсь, что в целом правильно делаю. Первый метод - это как раз тот, который мы тестируем, когда сам делаю запросы через postman к нему, то он всё выводит в консоль.

```
@GetMapping()
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
    public List<House> houseFree() {
        return houseService.findfreehouse();
    }


@Before
    public void AuthLogin() throws Exception {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setEmail("igor@mail.ru");
        userDto.setPassword("igor");
        authController.getLoginPage(userDto);
    }


@Test
    void ListHouse() {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        List<House> freeHouse = houseRestController.houseFree();
        assertThat(freeHouse.get(1)).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(
                new House((long) 8, "Квартира с видом на Кремль", 2, 20000.0, "Шахтера ул., 7")
        );
    }
```

Comment: если это assertj, то есть метод isNotEmpty() или hasSize(): assertThat(list).hasSize(2);
Но в целом по тесту не понятно что тестируется - контроллер, сервис?

Comment: У меня в контроллере сервис. Тестирую контроллер.

Comment: @RuslanP. В общем, я тут явно что-то не то тестирую? Ибо хотел протестировать контроллер, но как понимаю, нужно тестировать сервис?

Comment: Если это юнит-тест, то что тестировать в контроллере? Если интеграционный или сквозное тестирование, то надо подключать контекст спринга, поднимать тестовую БД. Юнитами обычно тестируют какую то логику

Comment: БД поднял, я моки юзаю: `@MockBean
    private HouseService houseService;

    @MockBean
    private HouseRepository houseRepository;

    @MockBean
    private HouseRestController houseRestController;`

Comment: Тестировать нужно/можно все. Здесь, судя по асертам, тестируется больше сервис, если затрагивает реальную базу см DataJpaTest . Контроллер также можно протестировать, но замокав сервисы (гуглить MockMvc).

Comment: @Blacit у вас все замокано и ничего не тестируется )

Comment: @RuslanP. так) Я пошёл распутываться. Буду тестировать сервис, мок убрал. Мок - это ведь просто имитация работы сервиса?

Comment: Да, заглушка, которая по-умолчанию возвращает null, пустые коллекции (как вы протестировали), а также можно задать свои результаты вызова (Mockito.when(...).then...)

Comment: @RuslanP. хрень какая-то, он всегда возвращает размер 0. Я хочу тестировать на null (потому что он может возвращать 0 по объективным причинам). Прописал вот так и конечно, он проходит тестирование, но по причине, что постоянно 0 отдаёт. `@Test
    void ListHouse() {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        List<House> freeHouse = houseService.findfreehouse();
        assertThat(freeHouse).isNotNull();
    }`

Comment: Ведь замокал всё правильно: `@Autowired
    private HouseService houseService;

    @MockBean
    private HouseRepository houseRepository;`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113795/discussion-between-ruslan-p-and-blacit).